# What is the best time to water a house plant?

Tags: watering

Is there an ideal time of day to water the average house plant? Does it depend purely on the plant, or are there times of the day (evening for example) when you should avoid watering them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the humidity doesn't vary much in the house, and you don't need to worry about spray evaporating, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Those plants will probably be screaming at you to water them when necessary.  Just make sure that when you water it is DEEP. I put my indoor plants in the shower once a month.  Not only to water deeply but to clean off the leaves, stems of dust and insects.  I set them outside on a covered porch during the summer to get even more light and nutrition stored in their roots to be able to thrive over the winter.  A splash of water is not enough.  A splash of water every day or every other day is a death sentence.  Except for a cactus...totally soak plants and then allow them to dry out in-between.  Critical methodology for plants...oh, except bonsai...need to be watered everyday, or every other day.  Outdoor plants, indoor plants this generality is important.

Answer (score 1):

I see this is a rather old question, but the answers don't address the over watering of houseplants problem. My wife has murdered **MANY** indoor plants, and the reason is very simple, she thinks they are thirsty ALL THE TIME. She believes that they are always thirsty. NOT TRUE!!

Always make sure you water the plant when the soil is DRY to the touch. Also: make sure there is a hole at the bottom of the pot so if you overwater them, the extra water can escape. Most plants sold at stores are put in "presentation" pots and covered in cellophane extra ..  unless you make the effort to remove the presentation wrapping and put a whole into the bottom of the pot, it is going to die. So if you want to keep it, make sure you allow the extra water to "escape" when you water it, otherwise it's going to rot and die.